# animate not work in the case of using autolayout

Tags: ios, swift2, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout

When I use this func，the animate not worked.

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var scanTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var scanView: UIImageView!
private func starAnimate() {
    scanTopConstraint.constant = -containerHeight.constant
    scanView.layoutIfNeeded()  //if I delete this code, the animate will work，but it is not I want to effect
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5) {
        self.scanTopConstraint.constant = self. containerHeight.constant
        UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(MAXFLOAT)
        self.scanView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

With this code, scanView just show the last status.

Could someone tell me why.

Thank for your reading and any help will be appreciated.